# How to link multiple iterations of a Javascript object to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a page that has to display multiple copies of the same Javascript object simultaneously - they will be manipulated individually later, so each element has to be linked a unique copy of the object.

I have this (very simplified) object:

```
function Person(index){
    this.index = index,
    this.name = 'Dave',
    this.photo = 'photo.jpg',
    // ... other properties ...
    this.changeName = function(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    // ... other methods ...
}
```

I use `document.createElement` in a for loop to create multiple divs, each of which should display the default name and photo, plus buttons to run functions that div only. The index is passed to the new object, and the divs are displayed in a container element.

```
function createPeople(num){
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
        const individual = document.createElement('DIV');
        individual.person = new Person(i);
        const index = individual.person.index;
        const name = '<p>' + individual.person.name + '</p>';
        const button = '<button onclick=changeName()>Change name ' + index + '</button>';
        // ... other HTML elements ...
        individual.innerHTML = name + button;
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(individual);
    }
}
```

The button shows the correct index, but I don't know how to make it's `changeName()` function target the specific object for that div, or for any changes in each object to be reflected in the correct div.

Answer (score 3):

Insert the button into the document, make sure you have a reference to it, then use `addEventListener` on it. Don't use an inline handler.

Also, to avoid undesirable possible unsafe scripts running, only insert *static* HTML with `.innerHTML` - for dynamic content from the user, use `.textContent`.

```
individual.innerHTML = `
  <p></p>
  <button>Change name ${i}</button>
`;
individual.querySelector('p').textContent = individual.person.name;
individual.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.changeName();
});
```

Assigning an `individual` instance to a property of a DOM element is weird though - if you need to use it elsewhere, consider making a `Map` mapping elements to their instances instead.